# Unity, 2d игра, алгоритм пути на с#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d

Кто-нибудь может подсказать алгоритм написания скрипта на С# в юнити для поиска пути

Comment: `1.`Это в двух словах не описать, там алгоритм просто громадный. `2.`В unity уже есть этот скрипт: `NavMeshAgent` называется.

Comment: Вы можете построить граф карты и обработать его с помощью, например, алгоритма Дейкстры.

Comment: [Поиск пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Поиск_пути)

Comment: Буду делать его через неделю или две , позже могу ответить .... пока вот есть полезная ссылка https://tproger.ru/translations/3-basic-distances-in-data-science/

Comment: Да, в юнити уже есть навмеш, но только он работает для 3d, я забыл указать, что работаю с 2d
Для 3d вопрос просто не актуален из-за навмеша